# How do I test for the occurrence of an error message and act on it?

Tags: fitting

I want to see how well some curves fit a data set. If a curve doesn't fit after 100 iterations, I get the error `cvmit`. How do I test for and handle this error within my code?

Answer (score 6):

I think `Check` will do it, e.g.:

```
 cvmitErrorFlag=False;
 Check[
    (* function that may throw error *) 
    Fit[ data, funs, vars ],
    (* what to do if error is thrown *)
    Print["No convergence within 100 iterations!"]; 
    cvmitErrorFlag=True,
    (* limit to only this error *)
    Fit::cvmit
 ]
```

Of course, you could be using other functions to do the fitting (instead of `Fit`).  You could also do things like `Quiet` the error message, in case you want to handle the convergence problem gracefully.